# From List to Graphical Interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, interface, inventory

I'm creating a shop inside my game to buy virtual goods.

### Main Shop Page

[image: Main Shop Page]

Each group has its own items. I've created a view where only one item is visible each time, with buttons to go to the previous and next item.

### Specific group selection Menu - Teams

[image: Specific group selection Menu - Teams]

The question is that I don't know how to show the **list** where I have the items, in that last window and make that touching the buttons previous/next the list shows the different items.

Each item inside the list is called `inventory[x]` (`x` = the number in the loop) and has the properties `itemName` and `itemDescription`.

How can I make the code communicate with the graphical user interface?

I've created 6 inventory lists (each one for one type of unlockable virtual good) and I use GameSparks API for online features such a player profile.

The lists are declared at the beginning of the script:

```
public static List<Inventario> inventarioEquipos = new List<Inventario>(); //Inventory for Teams
public static List<Inventario> inventarioPelotas = new List<Inventario>(); //Inventory for Balls
public static List<Inventario> inventarioModos = new List<Inventario>(); //Inventory for Modes
public static List<Inventario> inventarioVitores = new List<Inventario>(); //Inventory for Cheers
public static List<Inventario> inventarioCampos = new List<Inventario>(); //Inventory for Fields
public static List<Inventario> inventarioFondos = new List<Inventario>(); //Inventory for Backgrounds
```

In the Awake method I call:

```
    Info_Botones ("Equipos"); //I call this function for each group, to load its items and show how many items of a total of X the player owns. If you look at the first picture, will see below TEAMS: 1/2. That's what this function is for (besides to load all the unlockables in separated lists).
    Info_Botones ("Pelotas");
    Info_Botones ("Modos");
    Info_Botones ("Vitores");
    Info_Botones ("Campos");
    Info_Botones ("Fondos");
```

The code of the main function is as follows:

```
    private void Info_Botones(string tipoDeInventario) { //"tipoDeInventario" means InventoryType and I use it to pass to the function which type of inventory I want to load (Teams, Balls, Modes, Cheers, Fields or Backgrounds)

    int numero = 0;

    new LogEventRequest()
        .SetEventKey("INVENTARIO")
        .SetEventAttribute("TAG_TYPE", tipoDeInventario)
        .Send((response) =>
            {
                if (!response.HasErrors)
                {
                    List<object> entryList = response.ScriptData.GetObjectList("result") as List<object>;
                    for (int i = 0; i < entryList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> entry = entryList[i] as Dictionary<string, object>;

                        int itemId = i;
                        string itemName = (entry["name"]).ToString();
                        string itemDescription = (entry["description"]).ToString();
                        int itemPrice = int.Parse((entry["currency1Cost"].ToString()));
                        string itemInteractable = (entry["interactable"]).ToString();

                        Inventario inv = new Inventario(itemId, itemName, itemDescription, itemPrice, itemInteractable);


                        if(tipoDeInventario == "Equipos") {
                            inventarioEquipos.Add(inv);
                            if (inventarioEquipos[i].itemInteractable == "False") {
                                numero++;
                            }
                        } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Pelotas") {
                            inventarioPelotas.Add(inv);
                            if (inventarioPelotas[i].itemInteractable == "False") {
                                numero++;
                            }
                        } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Modos") {
                            inventarioModos.Add(inv);
                            if (inventarioModos[i].itemInteractable == "False") {
                                numero++;
                            }
                        } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Vitores") {
                            inventarioVitores.Add(inv);
                            if (inventarioVitores[i].itemInteractable == "False") {
                                numero++;
                            }
                        } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Campos") {
                            inventarioCampos.Add(inv);
                            if (inventarioCampos[i].itemInteractable == "False") {
                                numero++;
                            }
                        } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Fondos") {
                            inventarioFondos.Add(inv);
                            if (inventarioFondos[i].itemInteractable == "False") {
                                numero++;
                            }
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                    if(tipoDeInventario == "Equipos") {
                        txtBtnCantidadEquipos.text = numero.ToString() + "/" + inventarioEquipos.Count;
                    } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Pelotas") {
                        txtBtnCantidadPelotas.text = numero.ToString() + "/" + inventarioPelotas.Count;
                    } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Modos") {
                        txtBtnCantidadModos.text = numero.ToString() + "/" + inventarioModos.Count;
                    } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Vitores") {
                        txtBtnCantidadVitores.text = numero.ToString() + "/" + inventarioVitores.Count;
                    } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Campos") {
                        txtBtnCantidadCampos.text = numero.ToString() + "/" + inventarioCampos.Count;
                    } else if(tipoDeInventario == "Fondos") {
                        txtBtnCantidadFondos.text = numero.ToString() + "/" + inventarioFondos.Count;
                    } else {

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("ERROR AL OBTENER VG DEL JUGADOR: " + response.Errors.JSON);
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Can you post a mock-up picture of what you are trying to accomplish? What should the GUI look like? I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. I cleaned up the grammar in your post but I wasn't sure what this sentence meant: "The question is that I don't know how to show the list where I have the items, in that last window and make that touching the buttons previous/next the list shows the different items."

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. The "Equipo Argentina" text you see in the last image is the name of the first item in the LIST. I want that when I touch NEXT button, it replaces the info of first item in the list, by the info of the second item in the list... and so on. I want that it loops (when the user touches NEXT button in the last item it should show the first of the LIST again). And the opposite with PREVIOUS button. It should go backwards (from item 5, to 4, to 3...). Thanks for your time and sorry for my English level ;)

Comment: What you are asking sounds easy to do. However, it is necessary for me to know what your `inventory` list looks like.

Comment: I've updated the main post with the code. Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved it using IF condictions. If anyone needs the code, ask for it and I will share it (I'm not at home right now).

Thanks!